# How to animate zoom on jquery iviewer plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery plugin that zooms in on photos, but I would like to animate the zoom so it just doesn't zoom in, but so that there is like an animated effect on the zoom. Is this possible?

Here is the page I have the plugin set up on right now. http://www.buildinfocus.com/clients/gallery_detail.php?title=1&mapid=239

Maybe something like this http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Below is the code I have for plugin

```
(function($){

$.fn.iviewer  = function(o)
{
    return this.each(function()
                    {
                        $(this).data('viewer', new $iv(this,o));
                    });
}

var defaults = {
    /**
    * start zoom value for image, not used now
    * may be equal to "fit" to fit image into container or scale in % 
    **/
    zoom: "fit",
    /**
    * base value to scale image
    **/
    zoom_base: 100,
    /**
    * maximum zoom
    **/
    zoom_max: 800,
    /**
    * minimum zoom
    **/
    zoom_min: 25,
    /**
    * base of rate multiplier.
    * zoom is calculated by formula: zoom_base * zoom_delta^rate
    **/
    zoom_delta: 1.4,
    /**
    * if true plugin doesn't add its own controls
    **/
    ui_disabled: false,
    /**
    * if false, plugin doesn't bind resize event on window and this must 
    * be handled manually
    **/
    update_on_resize: true,
    /**
    * event is triggered when zoom value is changed
    * @param int new zoom value
    * @return boolean if false zoom action is aborted
    **/
    onZoom: null,
    /**
    * callback is fired after plugin setup
    **/
    initCallback: null,
    /**
    * event is fired on drag begin
    * @param object coords mouse coordinates on the image
    * @return boolean if false is returned, drag action is aborted
    **/
    onStartDrag: null,
    /**
    * event is fired on drag action
    * @param object coords mouse coordinates on the image
    **/
    onDrag: null,
    /**
    * event is fired when mouse moves over image
    * @param object coords mouse coordinates on the image
    **/
    onMouseMove: null,
    /**
    * mouse click event
    * @param object coords mouse coordinates on the image
    **/
    onClick: null,
    /**
    * event is fired when image starts to load
    */
    onStartLoad: null,
    /**
    * event is fired, when image is loaded and initially positioned
    */
    onFinishLoad: null
};

$.iviewer = function(e,o)
{
    var me = this;

    /* object containing actual information about image
    *   @img_object.object - jquery img object
    *   @img_object.orig_{width|height} - original dimensions
    *   @img_object.display_{width|height} - actual dimensions
    */
    this.img_object = {};

    this.zoom_object = {}; //object to show zoom status
    this.image_loaded = false;

    //drag variables
    this.dx = 0; 
    this.dy = 0;
    this.dragged = false;

    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, o || {});
    this.current_zoom = this.settings.zoom;

    if(this.settings.src === null){
        return;
    }

    this.container = $(e);

    this.update_container_info();

    //init container
    this.container.css("overflow","hidden");

    if(this.settings.update_on_resize == true)
    {
        $(window).resize(function()
        {
            me.update_container_info();
        });
    }

    this.img_object.x = 0;
    this.img_object.y = 0;

    //init object
    this.img_object.object = $("<img>").
    css({ position: "absolute", top :"0px", left: "0px"}). //this is needed, because chromium sets them auto otherwise
    //bind mouse events
    mousedown(function(e){ return me.drag_start(e); }).
    mousemove(function(e){return me.drag(e)}).
    mouseup(function(e){return me.drag_end(e)}).
    click(function(e){return me.click(e)}).
    mouseleave(function(e){return me.drag_end(e)}).
    mousewheel(function(ev, delta)
    {
        //this event is there instead of containing div, because
        //at opera it triggers many times on div
        var zoom = (delta > 0)?1:-1;
        me.zoom_by(zoom);
        return false;
    });

    this.img_object.object.prependTo(me.container);
    this.loadImage(this.settings.src);

    if(!this.settings.ui_disabled)
    {
        this.createui();
    }

    if(this.settings.initCallback)
    {
        this.settings.initCallback.call(this);
    }
}


var $iv = $.iviewer;

$iv.fn = $iv.prototype = {
    iviewer : "0.4.2"
}
$iv.fn.extend = $iv.extend = $.extend;

$iv.fn.extend({

    loadImage: function(src)
    {
        this.current_zoom = this.settings.zoom;
        this.image_loaded = false;
        var me = this;

        if(this.settings.onStartLoad)
        {
           this.settings.onStartLoad.call(this);
        }

        this.img_object.object.unbind('load').
            removeAttr("src").
            removeAttr("width").
            removeAttr("height").
            css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).
            load(function(){
                me.image_loaded = true;
                me.img_object.display_width = me.img_object.orig_width = this.width;
                me.img_object.display_height = me.img_object.orig_height = this.height;

                if(!me.container.hasClass("iviewer_cursor")){
                    me.container.addClass("iviewer_cursor");
                }

                if(me.settings.zoom == "fit"){
                    me.fit();
                }
                else {
                    me.set_zoom(me.settings.zoom);
                }

                if(me.settings.onFinishLoad)
                {
                   me.settings.onFinishLoad.call(me);
                }

            //src attribute is after setting load event, or it won't work
        }).attr("src",src);
    },

    /**
    * fits image in the container
    **/
    fit: function()
    {
        var aspect_ratio = this.img_object.orig_width / this.img_object.orig_height;
        var window_ratio = this.settings.width /  this.settings.height;
        var choose_left = (aspect_ratio > window_ratio);
        var new_zoom = 0;

        if(choose_left){
            new_zoom = this.settings.width / this.img_object.orig_width * 100;
        }
        else {
            new_zoom = this.settings.height / this.img_object.orig_height * 100;
        }

      this.set_zoom(new_zoom);
    },

    /**
    * center image in container
    **/
    center: function()
    {
        this.setCoords(-Math.round((this.img_object.display_height - this.settings.height)/2),
                       -Math.round((this.img_object.display_width - this.settings.width)/2));
    },

    /**
    *   move a point in container to the center of display area
    *   @param x a point in container
    *   @param y a point in container
    **/
    moveTo: function(x, y)
    {
        var dx = x-Math.round(this.settings.width/2);
        var dy = y-Math.round(this.settings.height/2);

        var new_x = this.img_object.x - this.dx;
        var new_y = this.img_object.y - this.dy;

        this.setCoords(new_x, new_y);
    },

    /**
    * set coordinates of upper left corner of image object
    **/
    setCoords: function(x,y)
    {
        //do nothing while image is being loaded
        if(!this.image_loaded)
        {
            return;
        }

        //check new coordinates to be correct (to be in rect)
        if(y > 0){
            y = 0;
        }
        if(x > 0){
            x = 0;
        }
        if(y + this.img_object.display_height < this.settings.height){
            y = this.settings.height - this.img_object.display_height;
        }
        if(x + this.img_object.display_width < this.settings.width){
            x = this.settings.width - this.img_object.display_width;
        }
        if(this.img_object.display_width <= this.settings.width){
            x = -(this.img_object.display_width - this.settings.width)/2;
        }
        if(this.img_object.display_height <= this.settings.height){
            y = -(this.img_object.display_height - this.settings.height)/2;
        }

        this.img_object.x = x;
        this.img_object.y = y;

        this.img_object.object.css("top",y + "px")
                         .css("left",x + "px");
    },


    /**
    * convert coordinates on the container to the coordinates on the image (in original size)
    *
    * @return object with fields x,y according to coordinates or false
    * if initial coords are not inside image
    **/
    containerToImage : function (x,y)
    {
        if(x < this.img_object.x || y < this.img_object.y ||
           x > this.img_object.x + this.img_object.display_width ||
           y > this.img_object.y + this.img_object.display_height)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return { x :  $iv.descaleValue(x - this.img_object.x, this.current_zoom),
                 y :  $iv.descaleValue(y - this.img_object.y, this.current_zoom)
        };
    },

    /**
    * convert coordinates on the image (in original size) to the coordinates on the container
    *
    * @return object with fields x,y according to coordinates or false
    * if initial coords are not inside image
    **/
    imageToContainer : function (x,y)
    {
        if(x > this.img_object.orig_width || y > this.img_object.orig_height)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return { x : this.img_object.x + $iv.scaleValue(x, this.current_zoom),
                 y : this.img_object.y + $iv.scaleValue(y, this.current_zoom)
        };
    },

    /**
    * get mouse coordinates on the image
    * @param e - object containing pageX and pageY fields, e.g. mouse event object
    *
    * @return object with fields x,y according to coordinates or false
    * if initial coords are not inside image
    **/
    getMouseCoords : function(e)
    {
        var img_offset = this.img_object.object.offset();

        return { x : $iv.descaleValue(e.pageX - img_offset.left, this.current_zoom),
                 y : $iv.descaleValue(e.pageY - img_offset.top, this.current_zoom)
        };
    },

    /**
    * set image scale to the new_zoom
    * @param new_zoom image scale in % 
    **/
    set_zoom: function(new_zoom)
    {
        if(this.settings.onZoom && this.settings.onZoom.call(this, new_zoom) == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        //do nothing while image is being loaded
        if(!this.image_loaded)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(new_zoom <  this.settings.zoom_min)
        {
            new_zoom = this.settings.zoom_min;
        }
        else if(new_zoom > this.settings.zoom_max)
        {
            new_zoom = this.settings.zoom_max;
        }

        /* we fake these values to make fit zoom properly work */
        if(this.current_zoom == "fit")
        {
            var old_x = Math.round(this.settings.width/2 + this.img_object.orig_width/2);
            var old_y = Math.round(this.settings.height/2 + this.img_object.orig_height/2);
            this.current_zoom = 100;
        }
        else {
            var old_x = -parseInt(this.img_object.object.css("left"),10) +
                                        Math.round(this.settings.width/2);
            var old_y = -parseInt(this.img_object.object.css("top"),10) + 
                                        Math.round(this.settings.height/2);
        }

        var new_width = $iv.scaleValue(this.img_object.orig_width, new_zoom);
        var new_height = $iv.scaleValue(this.img_object.orig_height, new_zoom);
        var new_x = $iv.scaleValue( $iv.descaleValue(old_x, this.current_zoom), new_zoom);
        var new_y = $iv.scaleValue( $iv.descaleValue(old_y, this.current_zoom), new_zoom);

        new_x = this.settings.width/2 - new_x;
        new_y = this.settings.height/2 - new_y;

        this.img_object.object.attr("width",new_width)
                         .attr("height",new_height);
        this.img_object.display_width = new_width;
        this.img_object.display_height = new_height;

        this.setCoords(new_x, new_y);

        this.current_zoom = new_zoom;

        $.isFunction( this.settings.onAfterZoom ) && this.settings.onAfterZoom.call( this, new_zoom );
        this.update_status();
    },

    /**
    * changes zoom scale by delta
    * zoom is calculated by formula: zoom_base * zoom_delta^rate 
    * @param Integer delta number to add to the current multiplier rate number 
    **/
    zoom_by: function(delta)
    {
        var closest_rate = this.find_closest_zoom_rate(this.current_zoom);

        var next_rate = closest_rate + delta;
        var next_zoom = this.settings.zoom_base * Math.pow(this.settings.zoom_delta, next_rate)
        if(delta > 0 && next_zoom < this.current_zoom)
        {
            next_zoom *= this.settings.zoom_delta;
        }

        if(delta < 0 && next_zoom > this.current_zoom)
        {
            next_zoom /= this.settings.zoom_delta;
        }

        this.set_zoom(next_zoom);
    },

    /**
    * finds closest multiplier rate for value
    * basing on zoom_base and zoom_delta values from settings
    * @param Number value zoom value to examine
    **/
    find_closest_zoom_rate: function(value)
    {
        if(value == this.settings.zoom_base)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        function div(val1,val2) { return val1 / val2 };
        function mul(val1,val2) { return val1 * val2 };

        var func = (value > this.settings.zoom_base)?mul:div;
        var sgn = (value > this.settings.zoom_base)?1:-1;

        var mltplr = this.settings.zoom_delta;
        var rate = 1;

        while(Math.abs(func(this.settings.zoom_base, Math.pow(mltplr,rate)) - value) > 
              Math.abs(func(this.settings.zoom_base, Math.pow(mltplr,rate+1)) - value))
        {
            rate++;
        }

        return sgn * rate;
    },

    /* update scale info in the container */
    update_status: function()
    {
        if(!this.settings.ui_disabled)
        {
            var percent = Math.round(100*this.img_object.display_height/this.img_object.orig_height);
            if(percent)
            {
                this.zoom_object.html(percent + "%");
            }
        }
    },

    update_container_info: function()
    {
        this.settings.height = this.container.height();
        this.settings.width = this.container.width();
    },

    /**
    *   callback for handling mousdown event to start dragging image
    **/
    drag_start: function(e)
    {
        if(this.settings.onStartDrag && 
           this.settings.onStartDrag.call(this,this.getMouseCoords(e)) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }

        /* start drag event*/
        this.dragged = true;
        this.container.addClass("iviewer_drag_cursor");

        this.dx = e.pageX - this.img_object.x;
        this.dy = e.pageY - this.img_object.y;
        return false;
    },

    /**
    *   callback for handling mousmove event to drag image
    **/
    drag: function(e)
    {
        this.settings.onMouseMove && 
                this.settings.onMouseMove.call(this,this.getMouseCoords(e));

        if(this.dragged){
            this.settings.onDrag && 
                    this.settings.onDrag.call(this,this.getMouseCoords(e));

            var ltop =  e.pageY -this.dy;
            var lleft = e.pageX -this.dx;

            this.setCoords(lleft, ltop);
            return false;
        }
    },

    /**
    *   callback for handling stop drag
    **/
    drag_end: function(e)
    {
        this.container.removeClass("iviewer_drag_cursor");
        this.dragged=false;
    },

    click: function(e)
    {
        this.settings.onClick && 
                this.settings.onClick.call(this,this.getMouseCoords(e));
    },

    /**
    *   create zoom buttons info box
    **/
    createui: function()
    {
        var me=this; 

        $("<div>").addClass("iviewer_zoom_in").addClass("iviewer_common").
        addClass("iviewer_button").
        mousedown(function(){me.zoom_by(1); return false;}).appendTo(this.container);

        $("<div>").addClass("iviewer_zoom_out").addClass("iviewer_common").
        addClass("iviewer_button").
        mousedown(function(){me.zoom_by(- 1); return false;}).appendTo(this.container);

        $("<div>").addClass("iviewer_zoom_zero").addClass("iviewer_common").
        addClass("iviewer_button").
        mousedown(function(){me.set_zoom(100); return false;}).appendTo(this.container);

        $("<div>").addClass("iviewer_zoom_fit").addClass("iviewer_common").
        addClass("iviewer_button").
        mousedown(function(){me.fit(this); return false;}).appendTo(this.container);

        this.zoom_object = $("<div>").addClass("iviewer_zoom_status").addClass("iviewer_common").
        appendTo(this.container);

        this.update_status(); //initial status update
    }
});

$iv.extend({
    scaleValue: function(value, toZoom)
    {
        return value * toZoom / 100;
    },

    descaleValue: function(value, fromZoom)
    {
        return value * 100 / fromZoom;
    }
});

 })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating to the latest version, it looks to support smooth zoom transition (so you won't have to implement this yourself):

https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/blob/master/jquery.iviewer.js#L415

On line 415, the `set_zoom` function animates the trnasition, as opposed to the older code you pasted, which just changes the css values.

Answer (score 0):

The last version of the plugin(0.5) supports smooth zoom, try it.